# multithread for loop push_back C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I need to benchmark some sorting algorithms, QuickSort, HeapSort... only about 2s, but others like BubbleSort is very time consuming (300k took about 45min). The CPU is just chilling at 20%. So I'm thinking about multithread to improve the runtime on multiple test case and size.
Pseudocode (from multiple smaller functions):

```
for each (testCase) //sorted asc, unsorted, sorted desc
{
    for each (sortAlgs) //order not important
    {
        for each (testCaseSize) //10k, 50k, 100k, 500k
        {
            arr = load_from_file(testCase, testCaseSize);

            //benchmark SortAlg mutiple times for better accuracy
            for each (repeat) //order not important
            {
                v.push_back(benchmark(sort(arr))); 
            }
            runtimeCase.push_back(average(v)); //order important
        }
        report_to_csv(runtimeCase); 
    }
}
```

I want to run multithread on loops that **order doesn't important**. However, `std::vector::push_back` is not thread-safe. So I think I have to use `std::mutex` (which I don't know how to use in loops). Also, I read `std::thread` doesn't return value so `std::future` is needed, and there's `parallel_for` in VS too. It's quite a handful for me and I don't know where to start. Please help me implement multithreading into the code.

### Update 1

I tried:

```
std::for_each(std::execution::par, v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto &n) {
    n = benchmark(sort);
});
```

But apparently g++ and VS2019 don't support it.

Answer (score 2):

> However, std::vector::push_back is not thread-safe.

You do not need synchronization when the threads read/write distinct elements and no thread causes a reallocation of the vector.

Instead of using `push_back`, resize the vector up-front:

```
v.resize( number_of_elements );
```

Then make sure no two threads are accessing elements at the same index.

PS: If your application utilizes only 20% of the CPU, then most likely performance of your application is not limited by CPU and I would not expect too much improvement by using multiple threads.

Comment: concerning the PS, I think I first misunderstand your code. If you want to run many benchmarks in parallel, then I would expect some improvement, but it may completely skew your measurments

Comment: It's just a compare between sorting algorithm for home assignment, so I think skew or not, BubbleSort can never beats something like QuickSort. I just want to try multithread for loop, just can't think how can I implement one.

Comment: @Phineas whether assignment or not, you shouldn't run benchmarks in parallel, because the result can be close to meaningless. However, my answer applies irrespective of what you use it for.

Comment: @Phineas concerning your update, you should explain what makes you think that gcc and MSCV don't "support" it. What does that mean? When you get compiler errors you need to include them. But please consider that your original question has an answer already, so changing the question to ask for something else is not nice. Consider to open a new question (including a [mcve] and the error message)

Comment: gcc straight up unrecognize `#include <execution>`, while my VS doesn't have for_each with execution argument, even though `#include <execution>` is recognized (and yes, already `#include <algorithm>`). Your answer is sure helpful, to which I tried to use it in Update 1 to solve my problem.

Comment: @Phineas comments are not for extended discussion or to answer questions. If you have a follow-up question please open a new quesiton. As I said the question you originally asked had an answer. Instead of changing the question to ask for something else by adding an "update" you should rather open a new question